# Conditions for dense set to be dense in compact subset

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

Suppose that $X$ is a compact connected metric space, $A$ is a dense subset of $X$, and $K$ is a compact subset of $X$.  $A$ does not have to be dense in $K$ (for example take $K$ to be the rationals in $[0,1]$, $A$ to be the irrationals in $[0,1]$ and $X$ to be $[0,1]$ itself).

What conditions guarantee that $A$ is dense in $K$?  Is it enough to require that $K$ be connected also?

Comment: The rationals in $[0,1]$ are not a compact subset.

Comment: Oh you're right!  Then would $A$ necessarily be dense in $K$?

Comment: No, not if $K$ has isolated points. I think conditions that will do it are if $X$ is second-countable and if $K$ is contained in the closure of its interior.

Comment: I just read that if $K$ has a non-empty interior then this works?

Comment: More than that. $K$ has to be contained in the closure of its interior. For example, if $K=[0,1/2]\cup\{3/4\}$, and $A$ is the irrationals, then $K\cap A$ is not dense in $K$. Also the second-countable part is also important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is true when $K$ is a regular closed set, so $K = \overline{\mathrm{int}(K)}$.
It is standard that $A$ is dense in $\mathrm{int}(K)$ and so $A$ is also dense in its closure $K$.

For non regular closed $K$ things can easily fail: $X = [0,4]$, $A$ the rationals in $[0,4]$, $K = [0,\frac12] \cup \{\pi\}$, then $\pi$ is not in the closure of $A \cap K$.

Comment: Fantastic answer, I couldn't of asked for better :)  I like the conditional counterexample also :)